# QGIS: Layer isn't shown at the correct location but is shifted

Tags: qgis, arcmap

**UPDATE 2:**
I even tried to reproject the layer in ArcMap, and it happens exactly the same as in QGIS, so the layer shifts slightly after reprojecting to EPSG:25832.
Could it be, that the CRS of the original file is a custom CRS?

---

**UPDATE 1:**
I asked a specific question to the reprojections here: [pyQGIS: Reproject between ESRI:103974 - Germany_Zone_3 to EPSG:25832](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/475105/pyqgis-reproject-between-esri31493-to-epsg25832)

Further, I inspected the layers more in detail.

The **base layer in ArcMap** is :
`EPSG:3857 WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere`

The **layer, which is correctly located in ArcMap** has this CRS:

```
Projected Coordinate System:    Germany_Zone_3
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  3500000,00000000
False_Northing: 0,00000000
Central_Meridian:   9,00000000
Scale_Factor:   1,00000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0,00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
Datum:  D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

When I reproject in QGIS to EPSG then the layer has this CRS (which does not align with the above CRS):

```
Projected Coordinate System:    ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  500000,00000000
False_Northing: 0,00000000
Central_Meridian:   9,00000000
Scale_Factor:   0,99960000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0,00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_ETRS_1989
Datum:  D_ETRS_1989
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

---

I have a shapefile which shows correctly in ArcMap but in QGIS it is a bit shifted.

This is the shapefile in ArcMap

[image]

And this is it in QGIS:
[image]

As you can see on the left side, there is a street which is a bit of a border when correctly displayed in ArcMap, but in QGIS the polygon lies over that street.

The CRS is ESRI-specific, maybe that is the cause?

This is the CRS of the polygon:

```
Projected Coordinate System:    Germany_Zone_3
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  3500000,00000000
False_Northing: 0,00000000
Central_Meridian:   9,00000000
Scale_Factor:   1,00000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0,00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
Datum:  D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

How can I correct it, so that it is correctly displayed in QGIS?
I will need to transform the shapefile to ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_N32 later on.

I would be very glad if someone knows how to handle this.

Comment: You have different basemaps. Not all basemaps line up either.  Have you tried using the same basemap in ArcGIS and QGIS?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not one of the base map that is shifted ?  Could you compare by using the same basemap ? also QGIS and ArcMap may use different transformation if a on the fly reprojection is used to display your shapefile did you check that ? are both project in the same CRS ?

Comment: It should not be so ESRI specific. Isn't it basically this crs https://epsg.org/crs_31467/DHDN-3-degree-Gauss-Kruger-zone-3.html? I can see that Proj suggests a few different operations for going from EPSG:31467 into EPSG:32632 (UTM). I think that you should provide coordinates of one point in the source coordinate system and in the target coordinate system as ESRI converts them.

Comment: Are the project CRS the same in Arc & QGIS?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, I also get multiple suggestions in QGIS to reproject them, and I tried each one of them, but it didn't help. How can I provide one coordinate?
For all others, I always use the basemap (it's a xyz-layer with google hybrid) and no data was shifted till now, therefore I assume, that it must be data which is not correctly projected.

Comment: I tried with qgis to reproject the data to epsg:25832. When I do that, the file lines up exactly the same as in QGIS, so a little shifted. 
I will open a new questions, where I specifically will ask how to reproject between those CRS.