# Reprojecting to EPSG:25832 using PyQGIS shifts layer

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

I have a shapefile with the following CRS specified in the prj. file, and I think it is ESRI:31493 :

```
PROJCS[
       "Germany_Zone_3",
       GEOGCS[
              "GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
               DATUM[
                    "D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
                     SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]
                     ],
               PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
               UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
              ],
       PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
       PARAMETER["False_Easting",3500000.0],
       PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
       PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],
       PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],
       PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
       UNIT["Meter",1.0]
      ]
```

I need to reproject this to EPSG:25832. However, I tried this with pyQGIS with a script and in the end, the file is reprojected, but when I open it in QGIS it is slightly shifted.

Important: This is also the case, when I open the file in QGIS directly. QGIS suggests three transformations, and I tried each one, but all had the same effect, which is, that the file is slightly shifted, so not in the correct location.

When I open the file in ArcMap it is positioned correctly, but when I reproject it with QGIS to EPSG:25832, then it is also shifted when I open it in ArcMap.

This is my script:

```
import qgis
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()


def reprojectShpFiles(inputfolderpath, outputfolderpath, crs):
    main_path = inputfolderpath

    for filename in os.listdir(main_path):
        if 'shp' in filename:

            file_path = fr'{main_path}/{filename}'

            INPUT = file_path 

            OUTPUT = outputfolderpath+'/'+ filename 

            processing.run("qgis:reprojectlayer",
                          {'INPUT':INPUT,
                           'TARGET_CRS':crs,
                            'OUTPUT':OUTPUT
                           }
                          )

            print('OK')
            print('------')


shapefiles = r'path\to\inputfolder'
outfolder = r'path\to\outputfolder'

reprojectShpFiles(shapefiles, outfolder,'epsg:25832')
```

How can I reproject the file correctly with PyQGIS?

EDIT:
Another information: When I load the correctly displayed layer in ArcMap, then the project CRS in ArcMap is as follows:

```
Germany_Zone_3
WKID: 31493 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting: 3500000,0
False_Northing: 0,0
Central_Meridian: 9,0
Scale_Factor: 1,0
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0,0
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
Angular Unit: Degree (0,0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0,0)
Datum: D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
  Spheroid: Bessel_1841
    Semimajor Axis: 6377397,155
    Semiminor Axis: 6356078,962818189
    Inverse Flattening: 299,1528128
```

Comment: Can you try a custom Projection? If you select Settings and Custom projections and paste your info into the projection. Then right click your layer and change the CRS to your new Custom Projection.  Does it look correct in QGIS??

Comment: Hi Cary, I did this in the meantime, so after transforming to UTM, in the .prj I adjusted the east and north parameter: PARAMETER["False_Easting",499924.5], and PARAMETER["False_Northing",-172.0]. This shifts the polygons to the correct location. 
How can I adjust this in pyQGIS?

Comment: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html  Shows how to make a CRS from a WKT - which you have.

Comment: Yes, I did add the custom CRS with ``wkt = 'PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",499924.5],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-172.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'        
out_crs = qgis.core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(wkt)``  But it is not adjusting accordingly, even though the .proj is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This works in QGIS

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
source_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(layer.crs().authid())

custom_wkt = 'PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989", DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]], PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]], PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",499924.5],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-172.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'
print("you got it")
custom_proj = 'WKT:' + custom_wkt
target_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(custom_proj)
with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    # you need to store the geometry in a variable to reproject it; you can not reproject without doing so
        geom = feat.geometry() 
        # transform the geometry
        geom.transform(QgsCoordinateTransform(source_crs, target_crs, QgsProject.instance()))
        # now update the features geometry
        feat.setGeometry(geom)
        # dont forget to update the feature, otherwise the changes will have no effect
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
        # finally simply set the layers crs to the new one
        layer.setCrs(target_crs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But is there a way to adjust the projection by using the processing module, as I did in my script?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be accurate.

```
import qgis
import processing
import os
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

wkt = 'PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",499924.5],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-172.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'         
out_crs = qgis.core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(wkt)


def reprojectShpFiles(inputfolderpath, outputfolderpath, crs):
    main_path = inputfolderpath

    for filename in os.listdir(main_path):
        if 'shp' in filename:

            file_path = fr'{main_path}/{filename}'

            INPUT = file_path 

            OUTPUT = outputfolderpath+'/'+ filename 

            processing.run("qgis:reprojectlayer",
                          {'INPUT':INPUT,
                           'TARGET_CRS':crs,
                            'OUTPUT':OUTPUT
                           }
                          )

            print('OK')
            print('------')


shapefile = r"C:\Users\Cary\Desktop\Junk\Herman"
outfolder = r'C:\Users\Cary\Desktop\Junk\Herman\OUT'

reprojectShpFiles(shapefile, outfolder, out_crs)
```

I used this file Hermannsdenkmal [Arminius](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYtqnZFOrw6Ho8FHLL2uAlXI_RUfylBI/view?usp=drive_link) It is all of your code.

Comment: Hey Cary, thank you for tryin to help! I still have the same problem with an offset of the data. I have uploaded an example shapefile, which contains a single polygon. Maybe you can try it with that data file? When I load it into QGIS, I get many tarball-conversation suggestions, but non of them really works. This is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/jr8g5v92h7azi73xf9cjw/h?rlkey=xgb5pk3z4rrqvl7um1v8scp9h&dl=0

Comment: It appears that your original data is shifted.  The file came in as  ESRI:31493 but does not look correct on a map.  It appears that the western edge should follow the rail.  Was this data collected or downloaded?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-11HB2BGsTNfMqtaIih-Q-AxSL24vNz/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hey Cary,  yes, in the foto of you it looks shifted, exactly as it is when I open it QGIS. In ArcMap it is not shifted when loaded, but afterwards, when reprojected.

Comment: Can you check the CRS of the "Correct looking" layer in ArcMap?  https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/check-the-coordinate-systems-of-the-data-frame-and-laye-000005357#:~:text=Check%20the%20Coordinate%20System%20of%20the%20ArcMap%20Data%20Frame%20by,and%20click%20the%20Source%20tab.

Comment: Hi @Cary H I added the CRS to the question!